# pandas interpolate barycentric backward

Tags: pandas, interpolation

I have series where the first data can be a NaN value. 
I tried interpolate( 'barycentric', limit_direction='both') but it does work if the first data is NaN:

```
pd.Series([ np.NaN, 1.5, 2]).interpolate( 'barycentric', limit_direction='both') 

0    NaN
1    1.5
2    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Is there a simple way to make it guess that the first number should be '1' ? Or is there a reason why it doesn't do it ? Other methods and directions don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with `limit` parameter in a way that fits your data, e.g.:

```
(pd
 .Series([ np.NaN, 1.5, 2])
 .interpolate(method = "barycentric", limit = 3, limit_direction = "both"))

0    1.0
1    1.5
2    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @alEx Why not accept the answer if it worked for you?